# ¿Cómo convertir un XML en un PDF conservando su formato en PHP?

Tags: php, xml, pdf

Necesito convertir un XML en un PDF conservando su formato tal cual se visualiza en explorer, como si fuera una captura de pantalla, ejemplo:
[image: Ejemplo]

Hasta el momento he probado con DOMPDF sin éxito, me gustaría saber si alguien ya lo ha realizado.

Gracias.

Comment: Cambia el contenido con `html_entities`, coloca todo dentro de un contenedor `<pre>`, completa el HTML y ya se podrá guardar sin problema.

Comment: Usando la etiqueta <pre> se imprime formateado, muchisimas gracias, ahora el tema es que sale cortado el texto, incluso en formato horizontal, mi código es el siguiente:
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape");
$dompdf->load_html($xml);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();

$xml es el texto que ya se imprime con formato correcto.

Comment: Agrega un estilo CSS para anular `white-space: nowrap` que tiene por default la etiqueta `<pre>`

Comment: Apliqué el estilo: <pre style='white-space: pre;'>{$xml}</pre>, realiza los saltos de linea, pero si un valor dentro de una etiqueta es demasiado larga no realiza el salto, se sigue incluso aunque se salga del margen del pdf, intente agregarle un width sin éxito.

Comment: Antes de cualquier cosa, pasa el código por [wordwrap()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.wordwrap.php) usando los 4 parámetros, el último en `true` para cortar aunque no haya espacios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usando una variante de [highlight_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php#84661), con un [XML de ejemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v%3Dvs.85))
y un par de mods para tabular / generar xhtml 1.1 válido

```
<?php
// https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v%3Dvs.85)

$elXML = <<<ELXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology
      society in England, the young survivors lay the
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters,
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing,
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
ELXML;

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php#84661
function xml_highlight($s)
{
  $s = htmlspecialchars($s);
  $s = preg_replace("#&lt;([/]*?)(.*)([\s]*?)&gt;#sU",
  "<font color=\"#0000FF\">&lt;\\1\\2\\3&gt;</font>",$s);
  $s = preg_replace("#&lt;([\?])(.*)([\?])&gt;#sU",
  "<font color=\"#800000\">&lt;\\1\\2\\3&gt;</font>",$s);
  $s = preg_replace("#&lt;([^\s\?/=])(.*)([\[\s/]|&gt;)#iU",
  "&lt;<font color=\"#808000\">\\1\\2</font>\\3",$s);
  $s = preg_replace("#&lt;([/])([^\s]*?)([\s\]]*?)&gt;#iU",
  "&lt;\\1<font color=\"#808000\">\\2</font>\\3&gt;",$s);
  $s = preg_replace("#([^\s]*?)\=(&quot;|')(.*)(&quot;|')#isU",
  "<font color=\"#800080\">\\1</font>=<font color=\"#FF00FF\">\\2\\3\\4</font>",$s);
  $s = preg_replace("#&lt;(.*)(\[)(.*)(\])&gt;#isU",
  "&lt;\\1<font color=\"#800080\">\\2\\3\\4</font>&gt;",$s);
  return nl2br($s);
}

$hlt = xml_highlight( $elXML );

// xhtml
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php#60251
$fon = str_replace(array('<font ', '</font>'), array('<span ', '</span>'), $hlt);
$elHTML = preg_replace('#color="(.*?)"#', 'style="color: \\1"', $fon);

// tabulación?
$elHTML = str_replace("  ", '&nbsp;&nbsp;', $elHTML);

// test
// echo $elHTML;

// https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($elHTML);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```